# Mouseover image popup on DataList not working in Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I am creating a images grid with Mouseover popup and using the [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/stickytooltip.htm) jQuery.

I am binding it on my `DataList` Mouseover working fine but the popup displaying same image of first image of `DataList`.

Take a look on the image below

[image]

.aspx code is

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListSearchResult" Width="97%" HorizontalAlign="left" AlternatingItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"
     RepeatLayout="Flow" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
     runat="server">
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
     <ItemTemplate>
          <table width="176" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="margin-left: 0px">
              <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                      <div class="thumbnail" id="div" style="width: 170px; height: 170px; margin-left: 5px;">
                      <div id="div1" class="thumb">
                      <img id="img1" alt="<%#gettitlethumb(Eval("ImageTag"))%>" data-tooltip="sticky3" src="TVQ/ThumbNail/<%#Eval("ImageFile")%>" />
                                                           <div id="mystickytooltip" class="stickytooltip">
                                                                <div style="padding: 5px">
                                                                    <div id="sticky3" class="atip">
                                                                        <a class="thumbnail" href="javascript:ImageDetailWindowNew('<%#Eval("IMGId")%>','<%#Eval("ImgCode")%>')">
                                                                        <img id="mousehoverimg" alt="" src="TVQ/Mouseover/<%#Eval("ImageFile")%>" /></a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                           </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
```

**.Css**

```
.stickytooltip{
box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #818181; /*shadow for CSS3 capable browsers.*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #818181;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #818181;
display:none;
position:absolute;
display:none;
border:5px solid black; /*Border around tooltip*/
background:white;
z-index:3000;
}


.stickytooltip .stickystatus{ /*Style for footer bar within tooltip*/
background:black;
color:white;
padding-top:5px;
text-align:center;
font:bold 11px Arial;
}
```

**.JS**

```
var stickytooltip={
    tooltipoffsets: [100, -30], //additional x and y offset from mouse cursor for tooltips
    fadeinspeed: 1000, //duration of fade effect in milliseconds
    rightclickstick: true, //sticky tooltip when user right clicks over the triggering element (apart from pressing "s" key) ?
    stickybordercolors: ["black", "darkred"], //border color of tooltip depending on sticky state
    stickynotice1: ["Press \"s\"", "or right click", "to sticky box"], //customize tooltip status message
    stickynotice2: "Click outside this box to hide it", //customize tooltip status message

    //***** NO NEED TO EDIT BEYOND HERE

    isdocked: false,

    positiontooltip:function($, $tooltip, e){
        var x=e.pageX+this.tooltipoffsets[0], y=e.pageY+this.tooltipoffsets[1]
        var tipw=$tooltip.outerWidth(), tiph=$tooltip.outerHeight(), 
        x=(x+tipw>$(document).scrollLeft()+$(window).width())? x-tipw-(stickytooltip.tooltipoffsets[0]*2) : x
        y=(y+tiph>$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height())? $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-tiph-10 : y
        $tooltip.css({left:x, top:y})
    },

    showbox:function($, $tooltip, e){
        $tooltip.fadeIn(this.fadeinspeed)
        this.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
    },

    hidebox:function($, $tooltip){
        if (!this.isdocked){
            $tooltip.stop(false, true).hide()
            $tooltip.css({borderColor:'black'}).find('.stickystatus:eq(0)').css({background:this.stickybordercolors[0]}).html(this.stickynotice1)
        }
    },

    docktooltip:function($, $tooltip, e){
        this.isdocked=true
        $tooltip.css({borderColor:'darkred'}).find('.stickystatus:eq(0)').css({background:this.stickybordercolors[1]}).html(this.stickynotice2)
    },


    init:function(targetselector, tipid){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var $targets=$(targetselector)
            var $tooltip=$('#'+tipid).appendTo(document.body)
            if ($targets.length==0)
                return
            var $alltips=$tooltip.find('div.atip')
            if (!stickytooltip.rightclickstick)
                stickytooltip.stickynotice1[1]=''
            stickytooltip.stickynotice1=stickytooltip.stickynotice1.join(' ')
            stickytooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip)
            $targets.bind('mouseenter', function(e){
                $alltips.hide().filter('#'+$(this).attr('data-tooltip')).show()
                stickytooltip.showbox($, $tooltip, e)
            })
            $targets.bind('mouseleave', function(e){
                stickytooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip)
            })
            $targets.bind('mousemove', function(e){
                if (!stickytooltip.isdocked){
                    stickytooltip.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
                }
            })
            $tooltip.bind("mouseenter", function(){
                stickytooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip)
            })
            $tooltip.bind("click", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation()
            })
            $(this).bind("click", function(e){
                if (e.button==0){
                    stickytooltip.isdocked=false
                    stickytooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip)
                }
            })
            $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e){
                if (stickytooltip.rightclickstick && $(e.target).parents().andSelf().filter(targetselector).length==1){ //if oncontextmenu over a target element
                    stickytooltip.docktooltip($, $tooltip, e)
                    return false
                }
            })
            $(this).bind('keypress', function(e){
                var keyunicode=e.charCode || e.keyCode
                if (keyunicode==115){ //if "s" key was pressed
                    stickytooltip.docktooltip($, $tooltip, e)
                }
            })
        }) //end dom ready
    }
}

//stickytooltip.init("targetElementSelector", "tooltipcontainer")
stickytooltip.init("*[data-tooltip]", "mystickytooltip")
```

Please help me to create this.

Comment: Can you post the full `Datalist` aspx code and its codebehind. I guess something is missing

Comment: Okay I'll update but its enough to bind data. vales are getting properly from database.When i use inspect element all the mouseover visible properly But populate only the first one.

Comment: put a break-point and check at what is getting Binded.

Comment: As I see from the demo in the link you provided the author has given 3 different names for data-tooltip of the thumb image. But here I see only one sticky which is sticky3. Try updating those dynamically with a number for each image!!

EDIT: and you have only one div to display image and it will same for all the images with same data-tooltip

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks for the reply but how to do it dynamically ?? please give me some hint for that i am very thankful to you :)

Comment: i think problem is `data-tooltip="sticky3"` & `<Div id="sticky3"`, this should change like `sticky1, sticky2, sticky3 ..` and so on

Comment: @AmitSoni how do Icreate ids dynamically  ?????????

Comment: i think this should work, Use `data-tooltip="sticky<%#Container.ItemIndex+1 %>"` & `<Div id="sticky<%#Container.ItemIndex+1 %>"`

Comment: You have any Id for image that you fetch from db??

Comment: Or you can just try data-tooltip='sticky<%#Eval("IMGId")%>' and same stands for your Div  <div id="sticky3<%#Eval("IMGId")%>" class="atip">

Comment: @AmitSoni i have create this like `data-tooltip="sticky-<%#Eval("ItemId")%>"` and `id="sticky-<%#Eval("ItemId")%>"` but only first popup display others are not displaying

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i have doing the same but after that only first popup is displaying others are not

Comment: In browser just right click on element and check what is the value of data-tooltip?

Comment: In browser  its displaying correctly

Comment: i just notice, where your `tr, td` closing tags ?

Comment: I found the Problem. the `mystickytooltip`  div is create only once. and the other `sticky-IDs` create inside the `mystickytooltip` Div. But how to do it not understand .@AmitSoni @GuruprasadRao

Comment: You see this needs lot of rework, because according to demo `mystickytooltip` div has to be created only once and all the other sticky divs should be inside `mystickytooltip`. But according to what you follow `mystickytooltip` will be created in each iteration. and as @AmitSoni said where are closing `tr,td` tags??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao is There any option to achieve this inside the `DataList` with the same jquery ??????????? And  `tr,td` closed properly after  `mystickytooltip` Div missing to add this.

Comment: I can explain it but as I said too much rework and cannot explain in comments. if you have any other means to communicate let me know.. I will help on this..

Comment: if you create a little example same like this only for understand i am very thankful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ok, Let's do this way**

suppose we have a gallery folder with images in it ( **1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on** )

As we know, datalist is itself shows data in table, so we dont need to create table, we just need to create images

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src='gallery/<%# Eval("src") %>.jpg' width="150" data-tooltip='sticky<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<div id="mystickytooltip">

</div>
```

Now, Our next task is to populate `mystickytooltip` with `div` and `image`

i did this task with **jQuery**
here's how i do this

```
$(function () {

    $("#DataList1 img").each(function () {
         $id = $(this).data("tooltip");
         $src = $(this).attr("src");
         $("div#mystickytooltip").append("<div id='" + $id + "' class='atip'> <img src='" + $src + "' width='200' /></div>");
    });

 });
```

[image]

**Note:** call this script before your `stickytooltip.js` script

Comment: really appreciate you effort Amit. But the pop is display with all images. take a look on this link.. http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fUiSEPtDjDk/VQFN8k0GYiI/AAAAAAAAFUo/kIIwmyQ87nU/s1600/asddsadsa.png%22

Comment: yes, that is why i said write above script before `sticky.js` script, let me edit my answer, you will get idea

Comment: a little black dot displaying on mousover :(

Comment: I am doing the same what you said but there is no image showing only a black dot displaying on the mouseover

Comment: inspect `mystickytooltip` div, check wheather it contains all the details we need with proper image source

Comment: not working with Paging and update panel.Please check once :)

Comment: hmm, with Paging and Update panel :P @Gitz